# Three.js не работает при нажатии кнопки

Tags: reactjs, three.js

```
loginError = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  var cubes = this.state.cubes

  var positions = [306,307,308,334,
                  331,356,382,408,434,
                  460,486,511,535,559,
                  583,607,631,656,681,
                  682,683,659,635,611,
                  587,563,564,590,616,
                  642,668,694,695,696,
                  671,646,620,594,568,
                  542,516,491,467,443,
                  419,395,371,346,321,
                  320,319,343,367,391,
                  415,439,438,412,386,
                  360]

  cubes.map((cube) => {
    var rand = Math.floor(0 + Math.random() * (positions.length - 0))
    cube.moveToX = cubes[positions[rand]].Cube.position.x
    cube.moveToY = cubes[positions[rand]].Cube.position.y
  })
  //alert("here")
}
```

код функции которую вызываем

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className={"loginPage"}>
            <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} className={"cirlces"}/>
            <CheckAuth auth={this.props.auth} direct={"/easybot"}/>
            <form className="formLogin">
                <h1 className={"p30 w150"} >Login</h1>
                <label className={"p30  w150"}>
                    Email:
                    <input type="text" placeholder="email" onChange={this.EmailChange} className={this.state.error ? "input" : ""}/>
                </label>
                <label className={"p30  w150"}>
                    Password:
                    <input type="password" placeholder="password" onChange={this.PassChange} className={this.state.error ? "input" : ""}/>
                </label>
                <button type={"submit"} onClick={this.loginError} className="btn" className={"p30 w150"}>Login</button>
                <p className="warning" className={"p30  w150"}>{this.state.error ? "Invalid email or password" : ""}</p>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

код откуда вызываем

Используется react js метод анимации стоит в componentDidMount
При нажатии кнопки некоторые элементы пропадают, и анимация не идет,
как это исправить?

Comment: а что лежит в `this.state.cubes`?

Comment: там лежат объекты которые хранять параметры для кубиков и сам кубик, проблема в том что эти методы работаю, если их вызывать в componentDidMount, но если через кнопку - нет

Comment: может, в консоли какие-нибудь сообщения об ошибках или предупреждения есть? без рабочего живого примера с кодом трудно в проводить дебаг :)

Comment: нет ошибок, я думаю что стоит вынести метод отрисовки, и попробовать так, метод отрисовки так же находится в componentDidMount

Comment: В момент когда мы достаем из состояния эллемент он имеет позицию nan и родителя так же nan